# What is the last column of Transformation matrix used for?

Tags: matrices, geometry, transformation

I've seen 4x4 Matrix used to represent 3D transformations. but last column seems to be always (0,0,0,1).

list of matrices for various operations: [Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/3d_transformation.htm#:%7E:text=Transformation%20matrix%20is%20a%20basic,matrices%20are%20used%20for%20transformation.)

Translation and Scaling:

$T = \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 
 t_{x}& t_{y}&  t_{z}& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$     
               
$S = \begin{bmatrix}
 S_{x}&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  S_{y}&  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  S_{z}& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Rotations:

$R_{x}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  cos\theta & -sin\theta& 0\\ 
 0&  sin\theta &  cos\theta& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  0& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$R_{y}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
 cos\theta& 0&  sin\theta& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0& 0\\ 
 -sin\theta&  0&  cos\theta& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  0& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$
$R_{z}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
 cos\theta &  -sin\theta &  0& 0\\ 
 sin\theta &  cos\theta &  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Shear:

$Sh = \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  sh_{x}^{y}&  sh_{x}^{z}& 0\\ 
 sh_{y}^{x}&  1 &  sh_{y}^{z}& 0\\ 
 sh_{z}^{x}& sh_{z}^{y}&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

So my question is, can I use 4x3 matrix to reduce calculations? what is the purpose of the last column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last column has two purposes. The first is to model vector addition. So normally if I want to find some matrix $A$ so that $Ax = x + a$ for some constant vector $a$ it's not possible. However if we add an extra row and column we can model [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) where vector addition can be done with matrix multiplication. This is useful when you're trying to encode local positional information with the translation as you can include it directly into the transform. This is done by replacing the $0$ entries of the last column with the vector $a$ and leaving the $1$ as is.

The second reason is for the [projective transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography). When calculating vanishing points and other artifacts of [binocular vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_vision) one step is to homogenize the coordinates, meaning we divide so that one of the coordinate values is $1$. Typically one coordinate is chosen for this so that all points can be compared to each other. For the transform object this will be the $1$ in the bottom right corner. So when you do a projective transform that entry will change and we can homogenize it to get the correct size and orientation of the object.

Comment: Yes, the fourth column accounts for addition but in terms of transformation, it accounts more exactly for a translation...

Comment: @JeanMarie I was under the impression affine meant linear transformations and translations. Is another definition more common?

Comment: No, your explanation is in fact perfect. I was just mentionning that this term "translation" could be useful, when for example you have to explain with words to students, for example when you say for example "rotation doesn't commute with translation"...

Comment: @JeanMarie I see your point. Thanks for the feedback. :)